# Is it possible to convert a material shader mask to geometry in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modeling, shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Hi I’m curious if it’s possible to convert a material shader’s mask into geometry somehow? I was thinking it might be possible with geometry nodes, but not sure how to access the shader mask specifically. Any ideas? I’m using Blender 3.3 btw. Thanks! Here’s a ss of what I"m talking about.

[image]